# Apache Flink Writing to MapR filesystem

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am currently running Apache Flink 1.2.0 in my current environment and was using BucketingSink to write data into hadoop file system.  I am able to write data using `file:///` and `hdfs:///` filesystem protocol without any problem.  Tested in Hortonworks Sandbox.  But when I switch to write with `maprfs:///` protocol in MapR Sandbox, it says

```
No FileSystem for scheme: maprfs
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: maprfs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
```

I need to understand what configuration I need to add into my Flink application in order to allow me writing to maprfs.  In my MapR cluster, the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml is empty, therefore, I did not copy to my `$FLINK_CONF_DIR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need mapr's `hadoop.jar` first in your classpath. Its usually sitting somewhere in `/opt/mapr/...`

Comment: Let me try recompiling Flink 1.2 with hadoop mapr dependencies and see how it goes.  I have read mapr community website saying in order to work with MapR clusters, we need to recompile Flink binaries using vendors repo.  I will use hadoop-2.7-mapr-1607 version for compilation.  Might also include zookeeper-3.4.5-mapr version in case facing any issue

Comment: FINALLY!!!!.  After recompiling Flink 1.2 with MapR dependencies, writing to maprfs is successful without even copying the hadoop mapr jars.  Everything works fine now.

Comment: You should accept @user7695690 answer as the correct one then :)

Comment: Actually having the hadoop jar doesn't seems working on my end, but recompiling Flink with MapR hadoop and zookeeper distribution helps solved my problem.  Nevertheless, accepted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [documentation page on how to set up Flink for Mapr](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/mapr_setup.html)

Comment: Thanks, the url link helps